# Adding another table to this sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

At the moment I have this sql statement to joint the three tables with the Players ID, but I would like to change this so that I can also join the playerdetails table. Below I have

```
"SELECT technicaldetails.*,
                            mentaldetails.*,
                            physicaldetails.*
                    FROM    PlayerDetails
                    INNER JOIN mentaldetails ON mentaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId 
                    INNER JOIN technicaldetails ON technicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId
                    INNER JOIN physicaldetails ON physicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId                       
                    WHERE playerdetails.playerID = " & DetailsPlayerID & ";"
```

The PlayerDetails table

```
PlayerID | FirstName | Lastname
-------------------------------
1        | John      | Smith
```

And Details tables look similar to this

```
PlayerID | Corners | Crossing | BallControl|ect...
-------------------------------------------
1        | 15      | 13       | 19
```

Comment: Is this in MS Access?

Comment: No sorry, the database is in mysql, but that sql statement is inside vb.

Comment: vb visual basic

Comment: ah - ok thanks for removing the tag.  (So VB6 i assume, not VB.NET) ...I was going to suggest using Access's Query Editor to build the query, then switching to SQL view and copying the SQL over.  I"m not sure if your setup that way to still do that (ie., if you do have Access capable of connecting to the same DB) because, especially with complex queries, it's a lot easier to build & test the queries in the visual editor.

Comment: No problem, I'm using sql workbench as a visual interface for my queries, but the main problem is that i'm unsure how to edit that sql statement so that the playerdetails table is also joined?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  All the tables are already in that code, right?  Is it not working?

Comment: Okay, that sql works, but I would like to change it so that it also has the playerdetails table included, currently i think the playerdetails is only used for the playerID

Answer (score 0):

> you can use below query ..

```
 SELECT technicaldetails.*, mentaldetails.*, physicaldetails.*,
 detailtable.* FROM PlayerDetails
 INNER JOIN mentaldetails ON mentaldetails.PlayerId =playerdetails.PlayerId 
 INNER JOIN technicaldetails ON technicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId
 INNER JOIN physicaldetails ON physicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId  
 left join detailtable on physicaldetails.PlayerId = detailtable.PlayerId                     
 WHERE playerdetails.playerID = " & DetailsPlayerID & ";
```

Comment: I can tell from the last couple characters that this is incomplete.  Also, you can format a `code block` by highlighting the code and pressing CTRL+K or clicking the `{ }` button on the toolbar..

Comment: Couldn't get that working, the playerdetails table i am getting the ID from is the table I am trying to add

Answer (score 0):

What you need is as simple as adding new selected columns. Your actual query begins with

```
SELECT 
    technicaldetails.*,
    mentaldetails.*,
    physicaldetails.*
FROM
    PlayerDetails
    INNER JOIN mentaldetails ON ...
    INNER JOIN technicaldetails ON ...
    INNER JOIN physicaldetails ON ...
WHERE
    ...
```

Note that you are telling the SQL engine that you want to see all (`*`) columns from the `technicaldetails`, `mentaldetails` and `physicaldetails` tables. Since you are already referencing the `PlayerDetails` table in your `FROM`, all you need is to add it's columns on the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT
    PlayerDetails.*,
    technicaldetails.*,
    mentaldetails.*,
    physicaldetails.*
FROM
    PlayerDetails
    INNER JOIN mentaldetails ON ...
    INNER JOIN technicaldetails ON ...
    INNER JOIN physicaldetails ON ...
WHERE
    ...
```

Would end up like the following:

```
"SELECT 
    PlayerDetails.*,
    technicaldetails.*,
    mentaldetails.*,
    physicaldetails.*
FROM    
    PlayerDetails
    INNER JOIN mentaldetails ON mentaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId 
    INNER JOIN technicaldetails ON technicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId
    INNER JOIN physicaldetails ON physicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId                       
WHERE 
    playerdetails.playerID = " & DetailsPlayerID & ";"
```

If you remove the `WHERE`, you would see the details for all players.

```
"SELECT 
    PlayerDetails.*,
    technicaldetails.*,
    mentaldetails.*,
    physicaldetails.*
FROM    
    PlayerDetails
    INNER JOIN mentaldetails ON mentaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId 
    INNER JOIN technicaldetails ON technicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId
    INNER JOIN physicaldetails ON physicaldetails.PlayerId = playerdetails.PlayerId ;"
```